# Android NullPointerException, but where?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

Ok, i got that I have a problem, I spent my last hours to find the problem, but I can not. From this LogCat how can I figure out what is the problem exactly?

```
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
ComponentInfo{com.example.transparentphone/com.example.transparentphone.MainActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2065)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at     
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2090)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:136)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at        
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4802)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:813)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:580)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at    
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at
com.example.transparentphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:207)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5013)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at   
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you please post the code?

Comment: Uhm, you're not supposed to post your entire file here, regardless what @sighrobot says. Since we already told you where the crash happened, a few line around line 207 (and marking which line is 207) is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

Start by looking at (and posting) line 207 of MainActivity.java, in `MainActivity.onCreate()`. If it's not clear from the source code, you can set a breakpoint on that line and see what's null.

Answer (score 1):

The part you're interested in is:

```
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 22:42:39.710: E/AndroidRuntime(5168):     at com.example.transparentphone.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:207)
```

So the crash happened in your `MainActivity.java` at line 207.